# Using RegGetValue to grab WOW64_64 keys

Tags: c++, windows, registry

Is there a way to use RegGetValue to get the 64 bit registry keys on a 32 bit application for older Windows operating systems (IE Win 7 or Win 8)?

```
RegGetValue(
  key, 
  nullptr, 
  "PRODUCT", 
  RRF_RT_ANY | RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY,
  dwType, 
  (PVOID)&buff, 
  &size);
```

`RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY` was introduced in Windows 10 and fails to work in Win 7/8.1

Comment: you need use `RegOpenKeyEx` + `RegQueryValueEx` instead `RegGetValue`.

Comment: [MSDN] Accessing an Alternate Registry View: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yea I know of that method, is there no way to just use `RegGetValue`? `RegGetValue` provides flags that allow you to specialize the call for certain registry types. Adding `RegOpenKeyEx + RegQueryValueEx` and then also checking for the type seems excessive where as `RegGetValue` is a single function